# Show a clock on jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show clock on jsp file, the time is fetched from server and is in `05 Jun, 2012 12:48:23 PM` format I want the same time to be updated rather than taking client time.

i did tried my hands on `timer.js`, `jtimer` and some other API's to do the same. I can do it by splitting the things and writing the whole clock logic myself but want to reuse the API that has already been developed.

Comment: in `timer.js` when i was doing `Date.parse("05 Jun, 2012 12:48:23 PM ")` it threw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i using this for many years:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Current Server Time script (SSI or PHP)- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
// For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/
// This notice must stay intact for use.

//Depending on whether your page supports SSI (.shtml) or PHP (.php), UNCOMMENT the line below your page supports and COMMENT the one it does not:
//Default is that SSI method is uncommented, and PHP is commented:

var currenttime = '<!--#config timefmt="%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->' //SSI method of getting server date
//var currenttime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time())?>' //PHP method of getting server date

///////////Stop editting here/////////////////////////////////

var montharray=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)

function padlength(what){
var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what
return output
}

function displaytime(){
serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)
var datestring=montharray[serverdate.getMonth()]+" "+padlength(serverdate.getDate())+", "+serverdate.getFullYear()
var timestring=padlength(serverdate.getHours())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getMinutes())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getSeconds())
document.getElementById("servertime").innerHTML=datestring+" "+timestring
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("displaytime()", 1000)
}

</script>

<p><b>Current Server Time:</b> <span id="servertime"></span></p>

<p style="font: normal 11px Arial">This free script provided by<br />
<a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></p>
```

for more informations see [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/servertime.shtml)

Comment: you need server side code to drive that, how can you run it by jsfiddle?

Comment: i expected that the service side date is already there with me and have kept it there in script

Comment: what template engine you are using at the server side for generating HTML? (asp, asp.net, PHP, mako , genshi , jsp) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing jQuery clock plugin that allow you to explicitly set the initial time.

For example [this plugin](https://github.com/Lwangaman/jQuery-Clock-Plugin) look nice and simple to use ([sample code](http://jsbin.com/ugapo3/72)) and allows you to set the time stamp, see under "Clock with custom timestamp".

So just pass the server time as the custom time stamp and you are all done.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, i would use Java date formatter from server side to format the date and add it to JSP  model. But, To answer this question, you can use Javascript Date class

```
var date = new Date('05 Jun, 2012 12:48:23 PM');
date.getMonth()
```

There are other methods that you can find here - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

PS: I'd google it first before posting this question for quick resolution.

Comment: have u tried this? it threw an error to me. Also the basic javascript is not allowing me to show it as clock. Need something to show it as clock